# Can I use any MQTT library to connect to an existing device with its own broker?

Tags: mqtt, iot, publish-subscribe, messaging, solace

I'm new to MQTT. I recently built a small simulation system, where I use Solace Pub/Sub Broker, and use Solace client library to build the message producer and consumer.

So now if I am provided a real device with its own broker and publisher, I just need to build the consumer client, can I use any MQTT library to code, or do I have to find out what the device has and use the same one?

I've tried with Solace but I do see that there are a lot more out there, if you guys have any recommendations I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Any MQTT client should be able to talk to any MQTT broker

With the assumption that both client and broker both support the same version of the MQTT specification, most clients support v3.11 and v5 and most brokers that support v5 also support v3.11 so you should be good, but you may have to specify the version number in the client when connecting.